# How to initiate multiple X login sessions at system startup?

Tags: linux, login, session, x-server, virtual-console

I have Linux Mint 17.2 KDE. I have several user accounts. I often use them at the same time for different tasks. My use case is like this:

1. Login as user1.
2. Start program A.
3. `Ctl+Alt+L` --> "Switch users" -- New X login session is started.
4. In this new session - login as user2.
5. Start program B.
6. Use `Ctl+Alt+F7` and `Ctl+Alt+F8` to switch between sessions of user1 and user2.

I would like to have 3 X login sessions started automatically at system startup, that I avoid using `Ctl+Alt+L` --> "Switch users" to start new sessions. How can I do that?

**Update:**
From the comment I understood that it can be done in display manager. In Mint I can see is used MDM. Do you have any idea how to configure it according to my needs?

Comment: Not familiar with what Mint uses by default, but usually you'd configure the [display manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_(program_type)). Some display managers don't allow autostart, then you'll have to use a different display manager.

Comment: In Mint I can see is used MDM. Do you have any idea how to configure it according to my needs?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used MDM. The source for the principal documentation seems to be [here](https://github.com/linuxmint/mdm/blob/master/docs/C/mdm.xml), I'd suppose there's a man-page or similar produced from that installed on your system. Reading the existing configuration files usually also helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the solution is to add to file `/etc/mdm/mdm.conf` in section `[servers]` config of other X servers:

```
1=Standard
2=Standard
```